# Pegando apenas 4 items de 1059 em vez de todos

Tags: php, json, api

Consegui resolver meu problema de pegar a data.
Atualmente meu problema é pegar todos os usuarios por algum motivo meu JSon está dando apenas 4 items de 1059 e eu quero pegar todos.

```
<?php 
function buscaUser($user)
{
$opts = [
        'http' => [
                'method' => 'GET',
                'header' => [
                        'User-Agent: PHP'
                ]
        ]
];
$user=  $_GET['username'];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$content = file_get_contents('https://api.github.com/search/users?q='.$user, false, $context); 
$json = json_decode($content,true);
$jsoncount = count($json);
echo $jsoncount."<br>";
for ($numItem = 0 ; $numItem <= $jsoncount; $numItem++){

echo "<img class='img-thumbnail' width='100px' height='100px' src=".$json['items'][$numItem]['avatar_url']."><br>";
echo $json['items'][$numItem]['login']."<br>";
echo "<a href=".$json['items'][$numItem]['html_url'].">Repositorio</a><br>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Sem o foreach vc consegue? esse código ai gera uns warnings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`items` é um `array` de *arrays*, você deve especificar o índice, fiz algumas pequenas alterações no teu código, veja:

```
function buscaUser($user) {
    $opts = [ 'http' => [
              'method' => 'GET',
              'header' => [ 'User-Agent: PHP' ]
            ]];

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $content = file_get_contents("https://api.github.com/search/users?q=$user", false, $context); 

    $json = json_decode($content, true);

    if ($json['total_count'] > 0) { // Se há dados
        foreach ($json['items']['0'] as $item) {
            echo $item . "<br>";
        }

        // Para acessar um item especifico
        echo $json['items']['0']['login'] . "<br>";
        echo $json['items']['0']['url'] . "<br>";
    }
}

$user = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : 'NaixSpirit';
buscaUser($user);
```

Para percorrer `items`, você pode fazer assim:

```
// ...
$json = json_decode($content, true);
$json_count = count($json['items']);

if ($json_count > 0) {
    for ($indice = 0; $indice < $json_count; $indice++) {
        $login = $json['items'][$indice]['login'];
        $url =   $json['items'][$indice]['url'];

        echo "$login, $url <br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: for ($numItem = 0 ; $numItem <= $jsoncount; $numItem++){

echo "<img class='img-thumbnail' width='100px' height='100px' src=".$json['items'][$numItem]['avatar_url']."><br>";
echo $json['items'][$numItem]['login']."<br>";
echo "<a href=".$json['items'][$numItem]['html_url'].">Repositorio</a><br>";
}
Meu problema é que agora eu só consigo puxar data de 4 dos 1059 items.

Comment: @RodrigoLessa Acho que é porque `$jsoncount` tem valor 4, confirme se é isso mesmo: `echo $jsoncount . "<br>";`. Outra coisa, `echo $json['items']['0']['login']` não resolve?

Comment: Não sei o porque o valor era 4 mas alterei o Jsoncount para $jsoncount = count($json['items']); e isso me retornou 30 valores. Acredito que por conta da api dividir em paginas.
"user_search_url": "https://api.github.com/search/users?q={query}{&page,per_page,sort,order}" só não tenho ideia como integrar isso no loop.

Comment: @RodrigoLessa *30* é valor correto? outra coisa, qual é a URL que você está usando? porque `https://api.github.com/search/users?q=NaixSpirit` retorna apenas **um** `array`de informações aqui pra mim.

Comment: Esse array era só um exemplo, existem varios outros dentro. No caso eu usava a api para pegar algum nome ($user no caso) da https://api.github.com/search/users?q= , isso retorna 30 items, um deles era Naix. Agora o que eu preciso é adicionar a paginação da propria API como https://api.github.com/search/users?q=spirit&page=2 onde retorna mais 30 e assim por diante.

Answer (score 1):

Ao invés de iterar o array(json) inteiro, especifique qual chave deseja (`items`).

O código abaixo itera as chaves `total_count`, `incomplete_results` que possuem valores escaleres (simples) logo um warning é gerada pois a chave `login` não existe, a seguinte é `items` como `$json['items']['items']` ou `$json['items']['items']['login']` não existem isso gera mais warnings.

Para resolver isso apenas especifique o 'ponto certo de inicio' do array.

Troque:

```
foreach ($json as $json) {
   echo $json['items']['login'];
}
```

Por:

```
foreach ($json['items'][0] as $item) {
    echo $item .'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Ficou dando erro "Array to string conversion".
Até tinha feito uma solução com um for

for ($numItem = 0 ; $numItem <= $jsoncount; $numItem++){
echo $json['items'][$numItem]['login']."<br>";
}
mas isso só trouxe 4 objetos do json apesar de exibir corretamente.